# Evaluate $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{4^n}{(2^{2^{n}}+1)^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have known that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{2^n}{x^{2^{n}}+1}=\dfrac{1}{x-1}$ for $x>1$.

Taking the derivative of both sides , 
 $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{4^nx^{2^n-1}}{(x^{2^{n}}+1)^2}=\dfrac{1}{(x-1)^2}$ .

This impiles
$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{4^n}{x^{2^{n}}+1}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{4^n}{(x^{2^{n}}+1)^2}=\dfrac{x}{(x-1)^2}$ .

Replacing $x$ by $2$ will get 
$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{4^n}{2^{2^{n}}+1}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{4^n}{(2^{2^{n}}+1)^2}=2$ .

But I have no idea to find $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{4^n}{2^{2^{n}}+1}$ .
Thank for helping.

Comment: Also used `\displaystyle` in title, another no-no. I've fixed. @NormalHuman

Comment: Your title series converges to something like $0.327443470\ldots$ so it doesn't look like a simple fraction. BTW: your summations should start at $n=0$.

Comment: Do you know of a proof for $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{2^n}{x^{2^{n}}+1}=\dfrac{1}{x-1}$ ?

Comment: From $\sum_{n=0}^m\ln{(x^{2^n}+y^{2^n})}=\ln{\prod_{n=0}^m(x^{2^n}+y^{2^n})} = \ln{\frac{(x-y)}{x-y}\prod_{n=0}^m(x^{2^n}+y^{2^n})}= \ln{\frac{x^{2^{m+1}}-y^{2^{m+1}}}{x-y}}$. Then take derivative with respect to y and substitue $y=1$ and take limit $m\to\infty$ will get the result.